# Error on getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Error on Public View onCreateView on getApplicationContext seems it wont work at my HomeFragment, but when I try this at my MainAcitivity it work. does anyone encounter this?

Thanks in Advance!
Here`s my Code:

```
package com.thesis.artificialintelligence;


import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;      
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;  
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;   
import android.view.LayoutInflater;   
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView resultTEXT;
private TextView resultTEXT2;
TextToSpeech t1;
private String package_calculator = "com.android.calculator2";
private String class_calculator ="com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
private String package_camera = "com.android.camera";
private String class_camera ="com.android.camera.Camera";
private String package_contacts = "com.android.contacts";
private String class_contacts = "com.android.contacts.Contacts";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.TVresult);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.TVresult2);

    t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() // There`s an Error here at getApplicationContext()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
            {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });




    return rootView;


}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{

    super.onDetach();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dear you can get Context using**

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragments do not have a `getApplicationContext()` method.

`TextToSpeech` only needs a context so you can replace it with `getActivity()`.

If you really want the application context do `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment than replace `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity()` and `getContext()`.